# Зачем нужные labels в k8s?

Tags: docker, devops, kubernetes

не понимаю, зачем нужны метки для deployment на данном конфиге
Не понимаю, зачем нужны метки именно для самого deployment, как они используются, если метки в template прикручиваются для подов, в selector, указывается, с какими родами нужно работать, зачем тогда метки на deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-hello
  labels:
  app: nginx-hello
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
  matchLabels:
  app: nginx-hello
  template:
  metadata:
  labels:
  app: nginx-hello
  spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-hello
  image: nginxdemos/hello
  ports:
  - containerPort: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Метки для Deployment выполняют ту же самую роль, что и для всех остальных Kubernetes  объектов - для упрощения идентификации и организации групп "логических" объектов.